# replace all whitespace in text file unless after # character

Tags: mysql, regex, perl, replace

I'm trying to replace all whitespace in a text file with a \t so that I can load the contents into SQL. The problem that I'm having is that I only want to replace white space before the a string containing a mix of white space and other characters.

Before:

```
1.5e-61   5.3e-58     132 0.99 # 3 # 398 # -1 # ID=6412_1;partial=11;start_type=Edge;rbs_motif=None;rbs_spacer=None;gc_cont=0.394
```

After:

```
1.5e-61\t5.3e-58\t132\t0.99\t# 3 # 398 # -1 # ID=6412_1;partial=11;start_type=Edge;rbs_motif=None;rbs_spacer=None;gc_cont=0.394
```

I essentially want to keep everything after the # character as a string. Can anybody help please?

Comment: People here won't write code for you.. Try approaching it like this; read the line character by character, replacing empty spaces. For the example you wrote, if the character == #, increase the loop counter by 1 to skip the next char(which in this case, is the empty space).. To learn how to do all that, use Google, it's quite basic.

Answer (score 1):

Parse, process, compose.

```
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ($data, $comment) = split(/(?=#)/, $_, 2);
   $data =~ s/\s+/\\t/g;
   print($data, $comment, "\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the OP meant the `\t` as a symbolic representation of the data, and not a literal string.  Perhaps?